# Build SQL query that summarizes total values for different categories and varying criteria

Tags: sql, subquery, postgresql-9.6

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and I am trying to create a single query on one table that can summarize a category's total area in different sites.
Below is a simplified version of my table.

```
Id  |  category (text)  |  area (real)  |  site (text)
 1  |   short grass 1   |      10       |     park 1
 2  |   short grass 2   |      15       |     park 2
 3  |   long grass 1    |      25       |     park 1
 4  |   long grass 2    |      18       |     park 3
 5  |   short grass 1   |      7        |     roadside 1
 6  |   short grass 2   |      4        |     roadside 2
 7  |   long grass 1    |      14       |     roadside 1
 8  |   long grass 2    |      7        |     roadside 3
```

- Id is the standard primary key setup
- Category identifies different lengths of grass (reduced for example)
- Area is a decimal figure for the area of the grass
- Site is the location of the grass

My finished table that I'm aiming for is the total area categorized by the grass category (column 2) and the site (column 4):

```
    site (text)        |  short grass   |  long grass
                          total area       total area
  park (grouped)       |      25        |      43
 roadside (grouped)    |      11        |      21
```

I thought I had some success using a CASE WHEN statement inside the SUM function, but instead of creating multiple rows with area totals based on varying criteria, it just added them together inside the single SUM, which in hindsight I realize is what I was asking it to do. (a brief example of my code below):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'short grass%' AND site LIKE 'park%' THEN area
    WHEN category LIKE 'long grass%' AND site LIKE 'park%' THEN area END) 
from my_table;
```

What I was expecting was two rows with the different area totals.  This is as far I've got with my code and I don't think I'm even going in the right direction with it.

I've considered nested SELECT queries and joins but my SQL knowledge isn't that great so I wouldn't know where to start to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT case when site like 'park%' then 'park' 
            when site like 'roadside%' then 'roadside' 
       --add else if required
       end as site,
SUM(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'short grass%' THEN area ELSE 0 END) as short_grass
SUM(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'long grass%' THEN area ELSE 0 END) as long_grass
from my_table
group by case when site like 'park%' then 'park' 
              when site like 'roadside%' then 'roadside' 
         --add else if required
         end
```

Comment: Hi @vkp  Thanks for getting back so quick I think I need to clarify my question a more.as 'site' isn't that simple I need to group the sites as well into a simple criteria as well.  I'll update my question

Comment: This is exactly what I was after.  I didn't know you case when to create new column. It looks embarrasingly easy now.  Thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define the groups?  If you just want the first word from `site`, then:

```
select substring(site from '#"%#" %' for '#') as sitetype,
       sum(case when category like 'short grass%' then area else 0 end) as shortgrass,
       sum(case when category like 'long grass%' then area else 0 end) as longgrass
from my_table
group by sitetype;
```